# Strange bug in OSGi bundle

Tags: osgi

I have a WAR package turned into OSGi bundle. I want to use PrimeFaces into the package. This is the POM file of the bundle:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.DX_57</groupId>
    <artifactId>History-Module-57</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>History-Module-57</name>
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi-cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-b41</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>           
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <supportedProjectTypes>
                            <supportedProjectType>ejb</supportedProjectType>
                            <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                            <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                            <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                        </supportedProjectTypes>
                        <instructions>
                            <!-- Read all OSGi configuration info from this optional file -->
                            <_include>-osgi.properties</_include>
                            <!-- By default, we don't export anything -->
                            <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>manifest</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>bundle-install</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin> 

                <plugin> <!-- Need to use this plugin to build war files -->
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <!-- Use version 2.1-beta-1, as it supports the new property failOnMissingWebXml -->
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <!-- add bundle plugin generated manifest to the war -->
                            <manifestFile>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                            </manifestFile>
                            <!-- For some reason, adding Bundle-ClassPath in maven-bundle-plugin
                            confuses that plugin and it generates wrong Import-Package, etc.
                            So, we generate it here.
                            -->
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Bundle-ClassPath>WEB-INF/classes/
                                </Bundle-ClassPath>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    <!-- We don't have a web.xml -->
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Enable this plugin for all modules -->
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>glassfish-repo</id>
            <name>The Glassfish repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>  
        </repository>  
    </repositories>
    <description>Module History Module</description>
</project>
```

When I deploy the bundle into Glassfish and I open the JSF page in order to use Primefaces components I get this error:

```xml
Warning: This page calls for xml namespace http://primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibtrary exist for that namespace
```

If I replace the  part with simple WAR package configuration Primefaces are working. It seems that there is something wrong into the POM configuration. Do you find something strange?

Best Wishes

Comment: I just love the typo in the question title :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing. We have a test WAB that uses primefaces which is working fine. You can find it here and compare and see what's wrong with your app:

https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/trunk/fighterfish/test/testapp/test.app9

I won't reply here further. Contact us in glassfish users list.

Sahoo